# internet explore uipath akabot RCA.Activities.IE System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has

Tags: internet-explorer, uipath

I have just login a ORC in Internet Explore using akabot, uipath. But I have get this error when open browser IE. Why and how can I fix it? Anyone help me.

Comment: #akabot #uipath

Answer (score 1):

I have just fix this error by using open browser IE in Try-catch activity, using Show Windows, Maximine Windows, then delay 3s with Open browser IE.[image]
[image]